# start xAxis and yAxis value from 0 and set custom xAxis value in Charts library

Tags: ios, swift

How to start xAxis and yAxis value from 0 and set custom xAxis value in Charts library?

As library will take values manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can set custom values for xAxis by using following code,

```
self.barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: self.arrUserCount)
self.barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
self.barChartView.xAxis.labelCount = self.arrUserCount.count
```

> use this lines to start xAxis and yAxis value from 0

```
self.barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
self.barChartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
```